# Probability tree problem with conditions

Tags: probability

I have a problem here, which I think I have solved, but not sure whether they are right or wrong.

> Suppose we have three assembly lines: A, B and C. The probability of a product to come from line A is 0.3, from B is 0.6 and from C is 0.1. The product may have a manufacturing defect if comes from line A at 0.1, from B at 0.4 and 0.15 if comes from C.
>
> a. Calculate the general probability of the product to be damaged.
>
> b. If it is known that the product has no defects, what is the probability of the product not to come from line C?

So I built up a tree:

[image]

Below are my solutions:

a.
A product has defects if it comes from A or B or C and has defects, so:

$P(D)=(0.3⋅0.1)+(0.6⋅0.4)+(0.1⋅0.15)$

b. The product should come from line A or B (not from C), thus:

$P(E)=\frac{(0.3⋅0.9)+(0.6⋅0.6)}{1-P(D)}$

Comment: Looks alright to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your answers are correct, since $$P(C^c | D^c)=\frac{P(C^c\cap D^c)}{P(D^c)}\\
=\frac{P(\{ao,bo\})}{P(\{ao,bo,co\})}=\frac{P(\{ao,bo\})}{1-P(D)}\\
=\frac{P(\{ao\})+P(\{bo\})}{1-P(D)}.$$